Finds elements in linkedin only after refresh
I am taking a course about browsers in tech school.
I have absolutely 0 knowledge in this field.
We were tasked with creating a simple chrome extension that runs at the background and when you are in https://www.linkedin.com/jobs it constantly searches for elements with the class jobs-apply-button.
Once it finds the element it prints it.
So I found what element contains the jobs-apply-button class. Its the Apply button:

So I created the following chrome extension:
manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Job Apply Button Checker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Logs elements with the class 'jobs-apply-button' every second.",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.linkedin.com/jobs/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}

background.js:
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
  if (details.url.includes('linkedin.com/jobs')) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: details.tabId },
      files: ['content.js']
    });
  }
}, { url: [{ urlMatches: 'linkedin.com/jobs' }] });

content.js:
function checkForJobApplyButtons() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.jobs-apply-button');
  if (elements.length > 0) {
    console.log('Found jobs-apply-button elements:', elements);
  }
}
setInterval(checkForJobApplyButtons, 1000);

Then I go to a LinkedIn -> Jobs -> Specific job that has that button.
But it doesn't work at first, nothing is logged to the console.
Only after I refresh the page its start working.
I tried multiple content.js techniques but same issue always.
Why does it work only after a page refresh, and how can I fix it?


Remove jobs/ from matches in manifest.json because it's a modern SPA site that reuses the same page internally, which means that content_scripts injection happens only when the site is first opened in the tab, so if the initial page wasn't jobs your content scripts will never be injected.
Remove chrome.webNavigation because you already have content_scripts.
Re-inject content_scripts after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome.

